# Imagem de fundo com styled-components no React caminho inválido?

Tags: react, image, import, styled-components

Estou tentando usar uma imagem como fundo de uma page em um projeto no react, pensei em importar com `styled-components` mas não consegui êxito, segue um `print` onde a imagem se encontrar, e como tentei chamar:

> [image: Localizar e importar imagem corretamente]

Comment: o que acontece?

Comment: fala que endereço nao foi encontrado

Comment: Entendeu a resposta?

Comment: entendi sim, deu certo, valeu!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu endereço está errado realmente, a pasta `src` (que significa `source`) é sua pasta raiz, ou seja, começa dessa pasta a leitura de todo o código e arquivos relacionados para que sua `app` funcione, então ***mude***:

```
.src/img/fundo.jpg
```

***para***

```
./img/fundo.jpg
```

o resto do código continua igual, então realmente o caminho é inválido.

Comment: obrigado! agora foi!